# How to run unit tests for x86 project

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, x86

I'm trying to add unit tests for my x86 .NET Core project.

I've created new project inside my solution and Visual Studio made it x64 by default. I added reference to the new project and tried to run an example test but it failed because there was a mismatch between projects' platform targets - x86 vs x64.

Then I tried to change platform target to x86 in the project with tests.

It gives me these warnings:

- > Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
  >   Project.UnitTests.dll is built for Framework 2.1 and Platform X86.
- > Exception discovering tests from Project.UnitTests: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Project.UnitTests, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
- > No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=Project.UnitTests.UnitTest1.Test1

Any ideas how to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also seeing the same problem having upgraded to the latest visual studio 2019 v16.1.3 and latest xunit (v2.4.1) & Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (v16.1.1)